Pass additional props to functional component
I have a constellation like this:
<AComponent>
  foo={{bar: AFunctionalComponent}}
</AComponent>

export default function AFunctionalComponent({
  // These are props that will get passed "automatically" by 'AComponent'
  foo, 
  bar, 
  baz
}) 
{...}

Now I want to pass an additional prop to AFunctionalComponent. How do I do that?

I'm not sure, but I think you want to achieve something like this:
import React from 'react';

export function AFunctionComponent({myPropA, myPropB}){
  return <p>Hello myPropA: '{myPropA}', myPropB: '{myPropB}'</p>;
}

export function AComponent({Comp}){
  return <div>
    Component: <Comp myPropB="B from Component"/>
  </div>
}

export function App(props) {
  const ProxyComp = (proxyProps) => <AFunctionComponent {...proxyProps} myPropA="A from Proxy" />
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <AComponent Comp={ProxyComp} />
    </div>
  );
}

By defining a 'Proxy'-Component, you can pass custom parameters.

Niceeeeee it did the trick! Thank you :)
